# sql server 2008 Sp2 install fails

Tags: sql-server-2008

HI
I am trying to install sql server 2008 SP2 but i get the error "File Corrupt" when the installer extracts the files. 
If i manually extract the files then also i get the "file corrupt" error.

I tried downloading the installer many times but all have the same issue

any help is much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this happen with downloaded Microsoft installers before. Something happens during transport that causes the file to become corrupt. We will need all the missing details and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Had to download the installer through a different ISP which seems to work.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.